# Blockscout: If there is missing data, do you retry?

Tags: indexing, blockchain

If there is missing data, do you retry?
If so, please provide details.

I'm involved in developing a service like blockchain inxer and comparing it to blockscout, etc. I would like to know more about the inner workings of blockscout.

And I am currently looking at the documentation around blockscout.

Thanks.